# Testing for polygon orientation using GeoTools

Tags: geometry, algorithm, geotools

I want to merge multiple geometries with Geotools (starting off with one geometry) but the result is a polygon that has a clockwise orientation. This gives an invalid geometry.

This is my code for the merge:

```
    GeometryCollection geometryCollection =
    (GeometryCollection) factory.createGeometryCollection(list.toArray(new Geometry[list.size()]));
    Geometry all =  geometryCollection.union();
```

Why would something give an invalid geometry and what can I use to test for orientation?

Comment: Perhaps somehow related to http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/jts-faq/jts-faq.html#B6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JTS polygons are clockwise (see http://tsusiatsoftware.net/jts/jts-faq/jts-faq.html#B6 for an explanation of why).

Why it would give you an invalid geometry is a difficult question to answer with out seeing your input polygons. Most likely causes are self intersection, self touching, invalid geometry in input list.

Comment: So if a geometry 'isValid()' then I should reverse it to be able to insert it into SQL server (using WKT). Any quick way of changing the orientation, or must I breakdown the polygon, reverse point order and create it again..

Comment: Sorry, should have read the whole answer mentioned above

Comment: Use the GeoTools data store and it will handle it seamlessly for you.